# Review of documentation change isn't recorded

Tags: bug, status-norepro, documentation, review-queues, documentation-review

When reviewing documentation, I got [this change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/122230) to review and I approved it. But after reviewing it, I went into the history tab and I couldn't see my review in there. And then when I went back in the review tab, I got to review the same change again. I approved it again and this time my review was visible in the history tab. As you can see in the link, it says that I only reviewed the change once. So it seems like my first review wasn't recorded. The same thing also happened on several other reviews.

I also went into [my review history](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/history?userId=4284627) to see if I may have pressed the skip button by mistake, but it doesn't say anything about that I skipped the review, only that I approved it once.

Why wasn't my review recorded the first time?

Comment: Caching, connectivity, bug, an act of God or something else. It worked the second time so what's the big deal, chalk it off and move on.

Answer (score 1):

I looked through the traffic logs and we only have one record of you clicking "Approve". Looks like the first time you clicked it is the time that counted.

As for why the same task appeared twice for you... good question. You voted to approve, navigated to history and back all within about 20 seconds, so it's possible something was just slightly out of sync. Hard to tell for sure. We'll dig further if there are other similar reports, but otherwise just chalk it up to a one-off oddity.